# How do you count number tasks in schedule per day in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, schedule

I'm trying to create a query in SQL Server that will return a count of tasks per day. If the start and finish date for a task are on the same day, then it should only add one to the count.

Here is a small example data set:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| ID | Start_Date | Finish_Date |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 24-Oct-16  | 24-Oct-16   |
|  2 | 24-Oct-16  | 26-Oct-16   |
|  3 | 25-Oct-16  | 26-Oct-16   |
|  4 | 26-Oct-16  | 27-Oct-16   |
|  5 | 26-Oct-16  | 28-Oct-16   |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Here would be the expected result:

```
+-----------+----------------+
|   Date    | Count_Of_Tasks |
+-----------+----------------+
| 24-Oct-16 |              2 |   
| 25-Oct-16 |              2 |
| 26-Oct-16 |              4 |
| 27-Oct-16 |              2 |
| 28-Oct-16 |              1 |
+-----------+----------------+
```

Can anyone create an example query that can count number of tasks per day?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `calendar` table to do this

I have used `Recursive CTE` to generate the dates between the start and finish date range on the fly. But it is always better to have a `Calendar` table created in database. It will be very helpful in such queries

```
;with data as
(
select * from (
VALUES
    (1, '2016-10-24 00:00:00', '2016-10-24 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2016-10-24 00:00:00', '2016-10-26 00:00:00'),
    (3, '2016-10-25 00:00:00', '2016-10-26 00:00:00'),
    (4, '2016-10-26 00:00:00', '2016-10-27 00:00:00'),
    (5, '2016-10-26 00:00:00', '2016-10-28 00:00:00')) tc ([ID], [Start_Date], [Finish_Date])
),calendar
     AS (SELECT dates = CONVERT(DATETIME, '24-Oct-16') -- Min Start_Date 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dates = Dateadd(DAY, 1, dates)
         FROM   calendar
         WHERE  dates < '28-Oct-16') -- Max Finish_Date 
SELECT c.dates,
       Count(s.Start_Date) AS Count_Of_Tasks
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT JOIN data s
              ON c.dates between s.Start_Date and s.Finish_Date
Group by c.dates
```

**Result :**

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║          dates          ║ Count_Of_Tasks ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 2016-10-24 00:00:00.000 ║              2 ║
║ 2016-10-25 00:00:00.000 ║              2 ║
║ 2016-10-26 00:00:00.000 ║              4 ║
║ 2016-10-27 00:00:00.000 ║              2 ║
║ 2016-10-28 00:00:00.000 ║              1 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: This worked very well, so thank you! As a side note, I had to add OPTION (maxrecursion 0) at the end of my query because of how large my data set is. It kept giving the error, "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion".

Comment: @user3174038 - yes..you have to add `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)` if the gap between start and end date is large

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.  One method breaks up the data and re-aggregates with a running sum:

```
select dte,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as total
from ((select start_date as dte, 1 as inc
       from example
      ) union all
      (select dateadd(day, 1, finish_date), -1 as inc
       from example
      )
     ) e
group by dte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(startdate),
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   tasks AS b
           WHERE  a.startdate BETWEEN b.startdate AND b.enddate
       )
FROM   tasks AS a 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(enddate),
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   tasks AS b
           WHERE  a.enddate BETWEEN b.startdate AND b.enddate
       )
FROM   tasks AS a
```